# Generating QueryDSL classes with maven fails since 3.1.0

Tags: java, maven, querydsl

When generating QueryDSL's Q... classes with the apt-maven-plugin the maven build fails with a `NullPointerException` in `SimpleSerializerConfig` - but only for maven versions since 3.1.0.

We already tried debugging into the maven build but that did not lead to any conclusions.

The maven configuration looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                <logOnlyOnError>true</logOnlyOnError>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <classifier>apt</classifier>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

with `${querydsl.version}` being 2.9.0 - using a newer version does not fix the problem.

The exact stacktrace is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:469)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:132)
    at com.mysema.maven.apt.AbstractProcessorMojo.execute(AbstractProcessorMojo.java:314)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:318)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:357)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mysema.query.codegen.SimpleSerializerConfig.getConfig(SimpleSerializerConfig.java:29)
    at com.mysema.query.apt.DefaultConfiguration.<init>(DefaultConfiguration.java:129)
    at com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAConfiguration.<init>(JPAConfiguration.java:69)
    at com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor.createConfiguration(JPAAnnotationProcessor.java:46)
    at com.mysema.query.apt.AbstractQuerydslProcessor.process(AbstractQuerydslProcessor.java:102)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:793)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:722)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1700(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:97)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1029)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1163)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1108)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:439)
    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This exception usually happens when there is a dependency conflict in the build. Try disabling the apt execution and see if there are other issues in the build.

Comment: Your answer pointed us into the right direction: Adding a dependency helped - we do not use spring data jpa, but after adding it as a dependency the build worked again.

Comment: Thanks I had a compilation error. It's unfortunate that the plugin doesn't output this...or run post compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Just sharing my experience with a similar error but a different cause in case somebody else runs into this.

The same error appeared after adding an annotation from a test-scoped dependency to a class in src/main/java. Eclipse didn't complain because m2eclipse isn't very good at distinguishing compile and test scoped dependencies and just adds every dependency to the project classpath regardless of the scope.

To see the actual compilation error, I had to perform the following steps :

1. make m2e-apt generate the QueryDsl classes in Eclipse
2. deactivate the annotation processing from the project's POM
3. run `mvn compile` (without `clean` to not delete the classes generated in step 1)

Comment: It 2023 now, and this solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this, too. We noticed that the cause was related directly to annotations. We added an annotation to a class that Maven proper was able to resolve, but mysema was not. We explicitly added the compile dependency to the pom in question and everything worked out.